# Mouseout event fires before mouse is actually out

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timeout, mouseevent

I have a mouseover / mouseout handler. Both use Javascript timeout to delay their job. But mouseout event triggers even when mouse is still over the selector. It works normally when timeout is turned off in mouseout script. So I suppose I do something wrong about timeout. It is something like

```
      $('.selector').live( {mouseover : function() {
          var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.something' ).show();
          }, 1000);
    }, mouseout: function () {
          timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.something' ).hide();    
          }, 2000);
    }
      });
```

Same thing happens if I use hover handler instead of mouseover / mouseout. And same thing if I use different variable names for two timeouts, or if I clear one timeout before calling another. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Works fine in FF, which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it works normally without timeouts I assume mouseover/mouseout is the correct event for you instead of mouseenter/mouseleave.

You are calling multiple timeouts constantly which are firing all over the place, you need to use a single timer that is only timing a single thing at one time:

```
(function () {
var timeout = 0;
    $('.selector').live({
    mouseover: function () {
    window.clearTimeout( timeout );
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.something').show();
        }, 1000);
    },
    mouseout: function () {
    window.clearTimeout( timeout );
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.something').hide();
        }, 2000);
    }
    });
})()
```

`window.setTimeout` just returns an ordinary integer number. Each time you call `window.setTimeout` a new timer will be created regardless of what variable the return value is assigned to. The return value of `window.setTimeout` can be used to clear a specific timer.

As a side effect, you can clear timeouts that you don't even know are existing. For example:

```
jQuery("div").fadeOut( 15000 );

var l = 10000;

while( l-- ) window.clearTimeout( l );
```

You are brute forcing 10000 different timer ids and clearing them all, taking out the jQuery fx internal timer which stops the fading out. Do not use in real code, for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: you should not bruteforce the timeouts. Jquery has a `.stop()` method for this exact purpose with more control and reliability.

Comment: @iliacholy, that was not the point but to demonstrate how timers work.  Running the code is not equivalent to .stop() at all, it actually breaks jQuery because it is not expected by jQuery internaly that the timers are magically removed from outside.

Comment: @Esailija yep just wanted to make sure the op was aware of this.

Comment: Ok people, then what is generally better: .stop(), or stopping timeouts from outside? I thought that .stop() is just for animations initiated by jQuery.

Comment: @cincplug do not mess with jQuery timeouts from outside, there are proper methods in jQuery to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the timeout so they don't overlap.

```
var timeout = null;
$('#foo').live({
    mouseover: function() {
        if(timeout !== null){ 
            clearTimeout(timeout); 
            timeout = null;
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#bar').show();
        }, 1000);
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        if(timeout !== null){ 
            clearTimeout(timeout); 
            timeout = null;
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#bar').hide();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/46mFc/1/